# Django Error: TemplateSyntaxError:

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Trying to get massivecoupon running and am running into a bunch of errors.

The most recent is:

File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    **import**(name)

> TemplateSyntaxError: Caught
>   ImportError while rendering: No module
>   named libsmassivecoupon.countries
>   Content-Type: text/html

The problem is that the module should be: massivecoupon.countries (which exists) and not libsmassivecoupon.countries (which does not)

The block of code in importlib.py that I believe is giving the error looks like this:

```
if name.startswith('.'):
    if not package:
        raise TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")
    level = 0
    for character in name:
        if character != '.':
            break
        level += 1
    name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
__import__(name)
return sys.modules[name]
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Usually template syntax error means the problem is actually in the template file. Seems weird it's referring you to that file.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here (I had the same) is that stack trace does not match the real place where stuff happens. One of the last frames of exception (removing the template one) is on an urls.py 's direct_to_template line, while the problem was a few line after, where i did include('.some.relative.module').

I just switched to absolute include() here to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what that snippet does since it doesn't say what `name` is, or what `package` is.  How about just ditching that and putting in a normal import statement for the modules you want?